# Подключение к mysql (написание интерфейса)

Tags: java, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с подключением к Базе данных. нужно сделать интерфейс и чтобы по нажатию кнопки программа подключалась к базе, а я не могу понять что нужно прописывать в коде кнопки. Mysql Connector скачал, но не знаю путь к нему нужно указывать в CLATHPATH?

Comment: Прочитайте вот [эту статью](https://tproger.ru/translations/java-jdbc-example/), если будут вопросы – пишите.

Answer (score 2):

Mysql-connector должен быть включен в jar-файл после компиляции, либо указан в classpath при запуске. 
Для использования его при разработке включите его как зависимость в вашей IDE.
Пример подключения jdbc с mysql: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Подключение зависимостей: 
В Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse 

В IDEA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project